# MEAN Stack: No token provided

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm making a blog as an assignement and every blog has a like button. When I click this like button I add a like to the blog at the backend (tested with postman). However, it doesn't work. If I log the data I get back from the backend to my console I get an error that says 'No token provided'.

This is what I get in my console:

```
{succes: false, message: "No token provided"}
    message: "No token provided"
    succes: false
    __proto__: Object
```

Here is my code.

product.component.ts [ likeProduct(id) ]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  messageClass;
  message;
  newProduct = false;
  loading = false;
  form;
  processing;
  username;
  producten;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) { }

  createNewProductForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(50),
        Validators.minLength(2),
        this.alphaNumericValidation
      ])],
      body: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(500),
        Validators.minLength(5)
      ])]
    });
  }

  disableFormNewProductForm() {
    this.form.get('title').disable();
    this.form.get('body').disable();
  }

  enableFormNewProductForm() {
    this.form.get('title').enable();
    this.form.get('body').enable();
  }

  alphaNumericValidation(controls) {
    const regExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/);
    if (regExp.test(controls.value)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { 'alphaNumericValidation': true};
    }
  }

  newProductForm() {
    this.newProduct = true;
    this.createNewProductForm();
  }

  reload() {
    this.loading = true;
    // Get producten
    this.getAllProducts();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    }, 4000);
  }

  comment() {}

  onProductSubmit() {
    this.processing = true;
    this.disableFormNewProductForm();

    const product = {
      title: this.form.get('title').value,
      body: this.form.get('body').value,
      createdBy: this.username
    };

    this.productService.newProduct(product).subscribe(data => {
      if (!data.succes) {
        this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger';
        this.message = data.message;
        this.processing = false;
        this.enableFormNewProductForm();
      } else {
        this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success';
        this.message = data.message;
        this.getAllProducts();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.newProduct = false;
          this.processing = false;
          this.message = false;
          this.form.reset();
          this.enableFormNewProductForm();
        }, 2000);
      }
    });
  }

  goBack() {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.producten = data.producten;
    });
  }

  likeProduct(id) {
    this.productService.likeProduct(id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.getAllProducts();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.username = profile.user.username;
    });
    this.getAllProducts();
  }

}
```

product.service.ts [ likeProduct(id) ]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  options;
  domain = this.authService.domain;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
    this.authService.loadToken();
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': this.authService.authToken
      })
    });
    console.log(this.authService.authToken);
  }

  newProduct(product) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.post(this.domain + 'producten/nieuwProduct', product, this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.domain + 'producten/alleProducten', this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProductById(id) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.domain + 'producten/geefProduct/' + id, this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }

  editProduct(product) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.put(this.domain + 'producten/updateProduct', product, this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }

  deleteProduct(id) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.delete(this.domain + 'producten/verwijderProduct/' + id, this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }

  likeProduct(id) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.put(this.domain + 'producten/likeProduct/' + id, this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

producten.js [ router.put('/likeProduct',... ]

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const Product = require('../models/product');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/database')

module.exports = (router) => {

    router.post('/nieuwProduct', (req, res) => {
        if (!req.body.title) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Product titel is verplicht'});
        } else {
            if (!req.body.body) {
                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Product beschrijving is verplicht'});
            } else {
                if (!req.body.createdBy) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Product creator is verplicht'});
                } else {
                    const product = new Product({
                        title: req.body.title,
                        body: req.body.body,
                        createdBy: req.body.createdBy
                    });
                    product.save((err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            if (err.errors) {
                                if (err.errors.title) {
                                    res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.title.message });
                                } else {
                                    if (err.errors.body) {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.body.message });
                                    } else {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errmsg });
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err });
                            }
                        } else {
                            res.json({ succes: true, message: 'Product opgeslaan'});
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    router.get('/alleProducten', (req, res) => {
        Product.find({}, (err, producten) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ succes: false, message: err });
            } else {
                if (!producten) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen producten gevonden'});
                } else {
                    res.json({ succes: true, producten: producten})
                }
            }
        }).sort({ '_id': -1});
    });

    router.get('/geefProduct/:id', (req, res) => {
        if(!req.params.id) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen id opgeven'});
        } else {
            Product.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, product) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen geldige id' });
                } else {
                    if (!product) {
                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Product niet gevonden' });
                    } else {
                        User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }, (err, user) => {
                            if (err) {
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err });
                            } else {
                                if (!user) {
                                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen authenticatie opgegeven'});
                                } else {
                                    if (user.username !== product.createdBy) {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen geldige authenticatie'} );
                                    } else {
                                        res.json({ succes: true, product: product});
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    router.put('/updateProduct', (req, res) => {
        if (!req.body._id) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen id opgegeven'});
        } else {
            Product.findOne({ _id: req.body._id }, (err, product) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen geldig id'});
                } else {
                    if (!product) {
                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Id is niet gevonden'});
                    } else {
                        User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }, (err, user) => {
                            if (err) {
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err });
                            } else {
                                if (!user) {
                                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen authenticatie opgegeven'});
                                } else {
                                    if (user.username !== product.createdBy) {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen geldige authenticatie'} );
                                    } else {
                                        product.title = req.body.title;
                                        product.body = req.body.body;
                                        product.save((err) => {
                                            if (err) {
                                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err });
                                            } else {
                                                res.json({ succes: true, message: 'Product geüpdatet'});
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    router.delete('/verwijderProduct/:id', (req, res) => {
        if (!req.params.id) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen id opgegeven'});
        } else {
            Product.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, product) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen geldige id'});
                } else {
                    if (!product) {
                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Product niet gevonden'});
                    } else {
                        User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }, (err, user) => {
                            if (err) {
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err});
                            } else {
                                if (!user) {
                                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen authenticatie opgegeven'});
                                } else {
                                    if (user.username !== product.createdBy) {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen geldige authenticatie'});
                                    } else {
                                        product.remove((err) => {
                                            if (err) {
                                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err});
                                            } else {
                                                res.json({ succes: true, message: 'Product verwijdert'})
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    router.put('/likeProduct/:id', (req, res) => {
        if(!req.body.id) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen id opgegeven' });
        } else {
            Product.findOne({ _id: req.body.id }, (err, product) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Ongeldige id'});
                } else {
                    if (!product) {
                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Product niet gevonden'});
                    } else {
                        User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }, (err, user) => {
                            if (err) {
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Something went wrong.'});
                            } else {
                                if (!user) {
                                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Geen geldige authenticatie'});
                                } else {
                                    if (user.username === product.createdBy) {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je kan je eigen post niet liken'});
                                    } else {
                                        if (product.likedBy.includes(user.username)) {
                                            product.likes--;
                                            const index = product.likedBy.indexOf(user.username);
                                            product.likedBy.splice(index, 1);
                                        } else {
                                            product.likes++;
                                            product.likedBy.push(user.username);
                                        }
                                        product.save((err) => {
                                            if (err) {
                                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err});
                                            } else {
                                                res.json({ succes: true, message: 'Blog geliket/disliket', product: product});
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return router;
};
```

authentication.js [ router.use... ]

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/database')

module.exports = (router) => {

    router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
        if(!req.body.email) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een email opgeven'});
        } else {
            if(!req.body.username) {
                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een gebruikersnaam opgeven'});
            } else {
                if(!req.body.password) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een paswoord opgeven'});
                }
                else {
                    let user = new User({
                        email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
                        username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
                        password: req.body.password
                    });
                    user.save((err) => {
                        if(err) {
                            if(err.code === 11000)
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Gebruikersnaam of email bestaat al' });
                            else {
                                if(err.errors) {
                                    if(err.errors.email) {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.email.message})
                                    } else {
                                        if(err.errors.username) {
                                            res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.username.message})
                                        } else { 
                                            if(err.errors.password) {
                                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.password.message})
                                            }                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Kan gebruiker niet registreren, Error: ', err });
                                }
                            }
                            } else {
                            res.json({ succes: true, message: 'Gebruiker geregistreerd'})
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
        if (!req.body.username) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een gebruikersnaam opgeven'});
        } else {
            if (!req.body.password) {
                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een paswoord opgeven'});
            } else {
                User.findOne({ username: req.body.username.toLowerCase()}, (err, user) => {
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({ succes: false, message: err});
                    } else {
                        if (!user) {
                            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Username niet gevonden'});
                        } else {
                            const validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
                            if (!validPassword) {
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Onjuist wachtwoord'});
                            } else {
                                const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, config.secret, {expiresIn: '24h'});
                                res.json({ succes: true, message: 'Succes!', token: token, user: { username: user.username }});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })

    router.use((req, res, next) => {
        const token = req.headers['authorization'];
        if (!token) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'No token provided'});
        } else {
            jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Token ongeldig: ' + err});
                } else {
                    req.decoded = decoded;
                    next();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
        User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }).select('username email').exec((err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ succes: false, message: err});
            } else {
                if (!user) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Username niet gevonden'});
                } else {
                    res.json({ succes: true, user: user});
                }
            }
        })
    });

    return router;
};
```

There seems to be something wrong in my middleware in authentication.js. It does work in other cases, so I don't see it.
Does someone see the mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Is your endpoint supposed to use the authentication middleware, or are you saying that you don't know why it's calling the middleware when you do not want it to?

Comment: It has to call the middleware since a user should not be able to like something when not logged in. So when he is logged in a token is saved in the local storage. But it seems like it can't get the token back when calling likeProduct.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question!